# Has_and_belongs_to_many with additional condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have entities: processes and users. They have many-to-many relations. But user can be assigned to process by different role: admin and owner (or both), and I use boolean columns in link table.

Here is my structure:

```
PROCESSES
    id
    name

USERS
    id
    email

PROCESSES_USERS
    id
    process_id: FK
    user_id: FK
    admin: Boolean
    owner: Boolean
```

Is there any way to make two different has_and_belongs_to_many association for these models using condition in boolean flags? 
I want to use it like this:

```
process = Process.find(1)
process.owners.size
process.admins.size

# Maybe even joins
Process.joins(:owners).includes(:owners)
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use has_many :through association
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many